# ITfoxtec Audience Validatiaon failed Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience:

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am getting this error using ITfoxtec
SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'System.String'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'System.String' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'System.String'.

Where can I set the Audience value.
MY appsettings are:

"Saml2": {
"IdPMetadata": "https://dev-16078540.okta.com/app/exk64xo640gcOOLQb5d7/sso/saml/metadata",
"Issuer": "Investx_SAML_Test",
"SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
"CertificateValidationMode": "ChainTrust",
"RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
}

I am working with an example from :
[Authenticate with SAML in ASP.NET Core and C#](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set the `AllowedAudienceUris` please see the ASP.NET Core [sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L38). Your applications issuer is the same as the audience because the token is for your application.